# how to display textbox in message box objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I want to display message box contain label and textbox and ok button and cancel button when the user press button in the main storyboard and get the string in textbox after the user press ok on IOS ?

i know how to display error message or something like that but i don't know how to display message box like that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                                        message:@"Enter File Name"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    [alertView show];



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Alert View dismissed with button at index %d",buttonIndex);

    switch (alertView.alertViewStyle)
    {
        case UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput:
        {
            UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"Plain text input: %@",textField.text);
        }
            break;

        case UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput:
        {
            UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"Secure text input: %@",textField.text);
        }
            break;

        case UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput:
        {
            UITextField *loginField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"Login input: %@",loginField.text);

            UITextField *passwordField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
            NSLog(@"Password input: %@",passwordField.text);
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```